# How to override lib in Spark-Submit?(scalikejdbc)

Tags: maven, apache-spark, spark-submit

I have Maven’s Multi-Module Project, with dependency - `scalikejdbc(ver.2.4.2)` in main POM. When I add in `spark-submit --jars xxxx.jar` with his `scalikejdbc(unknown_version)`, then an error occurs

```
ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scalikejdbc.NamedAutoSession$.apply$default$2()Lscalikejdbc/SettingsProvider
```

Question: how to prioritize the use of some libraries(`scalikejdbc(unknown_version)`) from your own project when use `spark-submit`?

If I set `--conf spark.driver.userClassPathFirst=true` and `--conf spark.executor.userClassPathFirst=true`, then occurs another error:

```
class org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter is not .....
```

And this is logical because there are not all libraries in the `xxxx.jar`.
Also, [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html) can't help me, as I will have to fix the whole project.